# How to collect activated checkboxes in powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, checkbox

I am using a WPF Application, made in Visual Studio, in Powershell. I am trying to figure out how I can collect activated checkboxes and run a command based on the selection. For now, I am trying to display a message that will show a user their selection to confirm before proceeding to the next step. For some odd reason,

`if ($checkbox.checked -eq $true)` does not work.

What i am trying to recreate is, if I have a listbox with the following checkboxes (all unchecked when the form starts):

`Apples
Oranges
Bananas`

and the user selects `Apples` & `Bananas`, I would like a message box to show that the user has selected `Apples & Bananas`.

`[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show(" show what the user has selected in this line"   , "selection")})`

and run commands that would be programmed to those selection.

for a more appropriate context, i am creating a GUI to add users to certain groups (the checkboxes to allow addition to multiple groups at once). I would like to let the user know exactly what user groups they have selected before proceeding to add to those respective groups.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: How are you initializing `$checkbox`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett the variables are initialized from the XML data obtained from Microsoft visual studio. i am using the tutorial found at [link]http://foxdeploy.com/2015/04/16/part-ii-deploying-powershell-guis-in-minutes-using-visual-studio/

Comment: You should add that link to the question. You should describe, in the question, exactly what input your powershell script is getting from the WPF application and how it is getting it. You should also show the code you have in your script which is attempting to show the message box. Then we may be able to figure out what's wrong with it. "My car doesn't work. For context, I'm driving to Houston next week".

Comment: That's a really cool example you linked to. I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: You really need to use the right property names... `If($Checkbox.IsChecked){}` it should be IsChecked and not Checked. Read part 3 of that series where he specifically addresses checkboxes!

Answer (score 2):

The property you want is `isChecked`, not `checked`. Simple example:

```
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Window" Title="Initial Window" WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen"
    SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight" ShowInTaskbar = "True" Background = "lightgray"> 
    <StackPanel > 
        <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBox1" Content = 'Value for checkbox one'/>
        <TextBox />      
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )

$CheckBox1 = $Window.FindName("CheckBox1")

$CheckBox1.Add_Click({
    if($CheckBox1.isChecked) {
        $CheckBox1.Content | Out-Host
    }
})

$Window.Showdialog() | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution posted by @sodawillow works. If you require to output the user's selection for confirmation purposes, the following bit of code will do just that.

```
for ($i=#; $i -le #; $i++){ if ($listbox.items.item($i).isChecked -eq $true)
```

`{$string = $listbox.items.item($i).content` 
`$collectionstring = @("$collectionstring" + "$string")}}`
`[System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$collectionstring" , "Status")`