# Unable to retrieve the checked rows from datagrid

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, powershell, xaml, user-interface

I am trying to create a simple Datagrid using WPF such that each row has a checkbox. I am having a tough time while retrieving the data. I am getting only 1 result. What can I fix in the below XAML

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="details" x:Uid="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternationCount="1" SelectionMode="Single" IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column" Margin="0,0,10,2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="410" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <CheckBox Content=" Select All" x:Name="headerCheckBox" />
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="chkDiscontinue"  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked,ElementName=headerCheckBox,Mode=OneWay}"   Margin="45 2 0 0"  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=file_name}" Header="File Name" Width="2*" IsReadOnly="True" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=file_path}" Header="File Path" Width="0.9*"/>
           </DataGrid.Columns> </DataGrid>
```

This is how I am trying to retrieve:

```
$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N'  -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = $inputXML
#Read XAML

    $reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
  try{$Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
    catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Double-check syntax and ensure .net is installed."}

#===========================================================================
# Store Form Objects In PowerShell
#===========================================================================

#$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name "var_$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name) -Scope Global  }
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name "var_$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name) }




$var_search_button.Add_Click({

    #JUST TO DISPLAY SOME RANDOM DATA(IT WORKS)
    $t = Import-Csv .\imp.csv
    $t | Select @{name = "file_name"; ex={$_.id}},@{name = "file_path"; ex={$_.name}} |% {$var_details.AddChild($_)}

    #TRYING TO RETRIVE THE ROWS WHICH I CHECK IN UI
    echo "__Show FORM DATA" | Out-File "imp.txt"
    $var_details.SelectedCells | Out-File "imp.txt" -Append
     $var_details.SelectedItems | Out-File "imp.txt" -Append
})


$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null

#-------------------------------------
```

Comment: How are you trying to get those values ? Show us your code, not just the xaml. It seems to be fine so it's your code behind.

Comment: Sir, I have updated the code as well. Kindly check

Answer (score 1):

I'm not used to use PowerShell but... talking about XAML, having your "IsChecked" property set to "True" isn't the same as being selected.

You should set your row to be selected everytime you check it.

```
 $var_details.SelectedCells | Out-File "imp.txt" -Append
 $var_details.SelectedItems | Out-File "imp.txt" -Append
```

You are asking for SelectedCells/SelectedItems and when you check you don't *say* they are selected.

I hope I explained myself :)

Comment: Hi Juan, Do you mean I will have to set some sort of EVENT for check/uncheck?   Frankly, I do not have any detailed understanding of XAML which I have pasted in question, but I am just trying to make it work somehow. If I get just a minor hint  I will be able to do so

Comment: Yes, you should set your checked/unchecked row to be selected/unselected everytime you check/uncheck your DataGridTemplateColumn

Comment: Sir, It would be a great help if you can suggest how can I achieve it from XAML.  I am not looking for cooked food but I have tried so many things that I am not even sure what else to try :)    is it possible to call a  PowerShell method from 'this' XAML??

Comment: Take a look to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232130/how-to-collect-activated-checkboxes-in-powershell  :) If my answer helped you, remember to upvote it and check it as an answer ;D